# XCode runs iOS Simulator, but Application never launches

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad

Trying some iOS development for the first time, and I'm attempting to follow some tutorials, however I'm having trouble making the Application actually launch within the Simulator.
The Application works fine when deploying to iOS Device, so it seems more like a Simulator issue.

I've tried on three different PCs, with many different test Applications. On each of them, the  Application will run on an iOS Device (in my case, an iPad 4, running the latest iOS (6)), but not in a Simulator.

I haven't been able to find anyone else with this particular issue (although it's hard to Google for, as the results mainly consist of irrelevant results about other Simulator issues), but I did try a few suggestions from similar situations. I tried changing the iOS Development Target to every option available (6.0, 5.1, 5.0, 4.3), turning off Code Signing, and recreating the project many times. None seem to have made a difference.

I'm running OSX 10.8.2, XCode 4.5.2.

Comment: What is the console says? Any screenshot available?

Comment: Are you able to launch simulator?

Comment: If you have tried on 3 different PCs I would suspect that it is an issue with your code. Device and Simulator are different enough where this could happen. Try with a new project (no additional code) and see what happens.

Comment: The console displays `error: failed to attach to process ID 0`, which I'm now Googling. Code isn't the issue, as the projects I've tried are  both blank projects, and projects with code that works on an iOS device. Showing the console looked like a good lead though

Comment: @ss23, Go to the Product menu and find the Edit Scheme menu.
In Edit Scheme window, select the "Run" option on the left hand side of the screen and then on the right hand side, change the debugger from LLDB to GDB. Check if that makes any difference

Comment: No luck. I've tried setting the debugger to GDB instead of LLDB, this resulted in displaying "Attaching to foo" displayed indefinitely.

Comment: I've tried deleting all the files in the places mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741188/error-failed-to-attach-to-process-id-0. I tried the 'Reset Content and Settings' in the simulator. I am not logged in as root. I cannot try uninstalling the application from the Simulator, as it never seems to be installed. However, I did note one user from the above post asked if the person was a network user. If it's relevant, I am a network user (not a local user). Permissions issues, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, the network user thing was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode which I also tried all the options on.